# Integrating dynamic content into mass email

Tags: email

We're looking for the best way to integrate dynamic content into emails sent by various individuals (or companies) using various mass mailing systems, some of them proprietary.

What are the options to do that and what are the advantages and disadvantages?

For example, I guess that one of the options is to add an iframe to the emails. In this case the url for the iframe content will carry a token which will identify the specific email, and our system will generate the iframe content.

Any advice on the subject is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most email readers won't allow you to input dynamic content into emails. Unfortunately there's no way round this other than asking the users to click a link to get to the content (something I've seen done before).

Answer (score 1):

Almost all email clients nowadays do not even download images from remote locations unless explicitly told to do so, let alone displaying `iframe`s. So your best bet will be to ask users to click some link.

Answer (score 0):

I created a multi threaded email mailer that has to generate unique content for each user.  Each thread is creating the body of the email.  Each section in the email has reference links to the detail page of that record inside the system